# How to make unclickable footnotes clickable?

Tags: hyperref, memoir, xfootnote

I have asked all kinds of questions but no solution so far this unclickable footnotes. The only thing I can say is that I'm having this problem since I started using the `memoir` class.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,frenchb,12pt,openany,twoside]{memoir}
\let\footruleskip\undefined %undefine footruleskip
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=57pt}
\usepackage{natbib}

%%%%Language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}


%%%%Police
\usepackage{lmodern}% police de caractère
\usepackage{textcomp}% caractères additionnels
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%Graphic
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%gestion de couleur des références;
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{candyapplered}{rgb}{1.0, 0.03, 0.0}
\usepackage{hyperref}                 
\hypersetup{hyperfigures = true, colorlinks = true, linkcolor=candyapplered}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}
\usepackage{footnote}

%%%%%Titling
\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%Math
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}%pour psshadowbox
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs

%%%%%géstion d'espacement
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%%%%Page Headings
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \cfoot{\empty}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %rappel du titre de chapitre
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}%rappel du titre de la section
 \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape  \thepage}]
 {\fancyplain{}{\slshape\rightmark} }
 \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape \leftmark}]
 {\fancyplain{}{\slshape \thepage}}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\textheight 24cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % supprime les en-têtes et pieds prédéfinis
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.85pt}% filet en haut de page
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % espace pour le filet
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % pas de filet en bas
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages de tetes de chapitre
\fancyhead{} % supprime lentete
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % et le filet
}

%%%%%%%%%gestion des chapitre,section;
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ14}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\sffamily\large\scshape}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{%
\chapnamefont\null\thickhrulefill\quad
\@chapapp\space\thechapter\quad\thickhrulefill}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
\par\thickhrulefill\par\vskip\midchapskip
\hrule\vskip\midchapskip
}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{%
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
\par\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{VZ14}

\titleformat{\section}
[hang]% style : hang, display, runin, leftmargin, ...
{\filright\sffamily\Large\bfseries}% fonte numéro + titre
{\thesection}% numéro
{0.5em}% espace entre le numéro et le titre
{}% fonte titre

\titleformat{\subsection}
[hang]% style : hang, display, runin, leftmargin, ...
{\filright\sffamily\large\bfseries}% fonte numéro + titre
{\thesubsection}% numéro
{0.5em}% espace entre le numéro et le titre
{}% fonte titre

%%%%%%%%%gestion des theoreme,lemme,preuve,remarque;
\newtheoremstyle{mes_theoremes}{0.45em}{0em}{}{}{\normalfont\filright\sffamily\bfseries}{\newline}{\parindent}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}

\theoremstyle{mes_theoremes}

\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{res}{Remarques}[section]
\newtheorem{exs}{Exemples}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Exemple}[section]
\newtheorem{Th}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{de}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{Le}{Lemme}[section]
\newtheorem{Not}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{re}{Remarque}[section]
\newtheorem{prts}{Propriétés}[section]
\newtheorem{prt}{Propriété}[section]
\newtheorem{co}{Corollaire}[section]
\newtheorem{con}{Contre Exemple}[section]
\newtheorem{col}{Conclusion}[section]
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution.}
%\newtheorem*{pre}{Preuve.}
\newtheorem*{hyp}{Hypothèses :}
\newenvironment{pre}[1][]%
{\par\parindent0pt\medskip\normalfont{\filright\sffamily\bfseries Preuve\ifx&#1&\else\space\no#1\fi.} \par}{\par\medskip}%

\begin{document}  
\chapter{Préliminaires}
\section{Notations et définitions}
Dans cette section, nous rappelons quelques définitions, notations et résultats d'analyse fonctionnelle (espaces, opérateur,$\ldots$) et quelques théorèmes qui nous seront utiles dans notre étude.\\ 

\noindent Soit $J=[a,b]$ un intervalle fini ou infinie de $\mathbb{R}$ où $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ et $a<b$ et soit $(X,|~.~|)$ un espace de Banach réel.\\
$\blacktriangleright$ $C(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions continues $y:J \rightarrow X$, muni de la norme 
$$\Vert y\Vert_{\infty} = \sup \lbrace |y(t)|~:~t\in J\rbrace.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $L^{1}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions mesurables $y:J \rightarrow X$ qui sont Lebesgue intégrable, muni de la norme
$$\Vert y\Vert_{L^{1}} = \int_{a}^{b} |y(s)|~ds.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $L^{\infty}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions mesurables $y:J \rightarrow X$ qui sont essentiellement bornées, muni de la norme
$$\Vert y\Vert_{\infty} = \inf \lbrace c>0 ~:~ |y(t)|\leq c~~p.p.\footnote{p.p: presque partout}~t\in J\rbrace.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $AC^{1}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions dérivables $y:J \rightarrow X$ dont la  première dérivée est absolument continue.
\end{document}
```

These are the results after using the solution in the accepted answer below,

[image: the footnote is unclickable]

[image: Warrnings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that package `hyperref` should be in your case the last called package!

Another issue here is that you should `french` as class option and option for `babel` to get rid of the relevant warning.

You should rework the packages you call and the order of calling ... Do you really need all that packages? Do you understand what they do? Please use only packages you know or you have read the documentation (for example with `texdoc hyperref` in your console/terminal).

Please see the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,openany,twoside]{memoir} % <=========
\let\footruleskip\undefined %undefine footruleskip
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=57pt}
\usepackage{natbib}

%%%%Language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % <==========================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}


%%%%Police
\usepackage{lmodern}% police de caractère
\usepackage{textcomp}% caractères additionnels
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%Graphic
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{candyapplered}{rgb}{1.0, 0.03, 0.0}

\usepackage{footnote}

%%%%%Titling
\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%Math
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}%pour psshadowbox
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs

%%%%%géstion d'espacement
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage[hyperfigures=true]{hyperref} % <================================ last called package
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor=candyapplered}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}

%%%%Page Headings
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \cfoot{\empty}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %rappel du titre de chapitre
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}%rappel du titre de la section
 \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape  \thepage}]
 {\fancyplain{}{\slshape\rightmark} }
 \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape \leftmark}]
 {\fancyplain{}{\slshape \thepage}}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\textheight 24cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % supprime les en-têtes et pieds prédéfinis
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.85pt}% filet en haut de page
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % espace pour le filet
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % pas de filet en bas
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages de tetes de chapitre
\fancyhead{} % supprime lentete
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % et le filet
}

%%%%%%%%%gestion des chapitre,section;
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ14}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\sffamily\large\scshape}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{%
\chapnamefont\null\thickhrulefill\quad
\@chapapp\space\thechapter\quad\thickhrulefill}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
\par\thickhrulefill\par\vskip\midchapskip
\hrule\vskip\midchapskip
}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{%
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
\par\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{VZ14}

\titleformat{\section}
[hang]% style : hang, display, runin, leftmargin, ...
{\filright\sffamily\Large\bfseries}% fonte numéro + titre
{\thesection}% numéro
{0.5em}% espace entre le numéro et le titre
{}% fonte titre

\titleformat{\subsection}
[hang]% style : hang, display, runin, leftmargin, ...
{\filright\sffamily\large\bfseries}% fonte numéro + titre
{\thesubsection}% numéro
{0.5em}% espace entre le numéro et le titre
{}% fonte titre

%%%%%%%%%gestion des theoreme,lemme,preuve,remarque;
\newtheoremstyle{mes_theoremes}{0.45em}{0em}{}{}{\normalfont\filright\sffamily\bfseries}{\newline}{\parindent}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}

\theoremstyle{mes_theoremes}

\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{res}{Remarques}[section]
\newtheorem{exs}{Exemples}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Exemple}[section]
\newtheorem{Th}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{de}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{Le}{Lemme}[section]
\newtheorem{Not}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{re}{Remarque}[section]
\newtheorem{prts}{Propriétés}[section]
\newtheorem{prt}{Propriété}[section]
\newtheorem{co}{Corollaire}[section]
\newtheorem{con}{Contre Exemple}[section]
\newtheorem{col}{Conclusion}[section]
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution.}
%\newtheorem*{pre}{Preuve.}
\newtheorem*{hyp}{Hypothèses :}
\newenvironment{pre}[1][]%
{\par\parindent0pt\medskip\normalfont{\filright\sffamily\bfseries Preuve\ifx&#1&\else\space\no#1\fi.} \par}{\par\medskip}%


\begin{document}

\chapter{Préliminaires}
\section{Notations et définitions}
Dans cette section, nous rappelons quelques définitions, notations et 
résultats d'analyse fonctionnelle (espaces, opérateur,$\ldots$) et 
quelques théorèmes qui nous seront utiles dans notre étude. 
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484190}

\noindent Soit $J=[a,b]$ un intervalle fini ou infinie de $\mathbb{R}$ 
où $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ et $a<b$ et soit $(X,|~.~|)$ un espace de Banach 
réel.

$\blacktriangleright$ $C(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions continues 
$y:J \rightarrow X$, muni de la norme 
$$\Vert y\Vert_{\infty} = \sup \lbrace |y(t)|~:~t\in J\rbrace.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $L^{1}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions 
mesurables $y:J \rightarrow X$ qui sont Lebesgue intégrable, muni de la 
norme
$$\Vert y\Vert_{L^{1}} = \int_{a}^{b} |y(s)|~ds.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $L^{\infty}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions 
mesurables $y:J \rightarrow X$ qui sont essentiellement bornées, muni de 
la norme
$$\Vert y\Vert_{\infty} = \inf \lbrace c>0 ~:~ |y(t)|\leq c~~p.p.\footnote{p.p: presque partout}~t\in J\rbrace.$$
$\blacktriangleright$ $AC^{1}(J,X)$ l'espace de Banach des fonctions 
dérivables $y:J \rightarrow X$ dont la  première dérivée est absolument 
continue.
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result]

## Edit:

Your used MiKTeX is too old, please update your system!

Comment: thank you. The update got rid of the malfunction as you suggested.